# OpenEIS with VOLTTRON

Tags: volttron

When trying to use OpenEIS in VOLTTRON, I first need to install OpenEIS.

I managed to install Python 3.4, so I can run "python3 bootstrap.py" under ~/openeis-2.x

I managed to change the get-pip link in bootstrap to https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

However, when I ran the command, I got a series of error messages, the first two I am trying to overcome is "import pip ImportError: No module named 'pip' " and import ensurepip ImportError: No module named 'ensurepip'"

Isn't the purpose of downlaoding get-pip from the link, so I don't need to have pip and ensurepip when I run the code?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The question title is very confusing: "OpenEIS in Volttron"?

Comment: I am trying to install OpenEIS. It can be installed in Windows or Linux with VOLTTRON. I tried to run the bootstrap.py but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OpenEIS and VOLTTRON use two different versions of python.  The get-pip script is specific to VOLTTRON as it is necessary for the 2.7 version of python in order to install pip.  With OpenEIS pip is already installed so it shouldn't need to get-pip.

In order to get OpenEIS and VOLTTRON working you first need to get them installed separately.  Once you have them running then you can use the OpenEISHistorian from VOLTTRON to send data to the OpenEIS instance.

I hope that helps and clears up some of the confusion that you are having.

Comment: I am following [link](http://transactionalnetwork.pnnl.gov/documents/PNNL-24065_OpenEIS_User_Guide.pdf), let me know if it is no good.

I had VOLTTRON; I was not able to install OpenEIS.

I had Python 3.3 or greater; I ran `python3 -V` under ~/openeis-2.x, and got Python 3.4.3

But I ran `python3.4 bootstrap.py`, I received:

File "bootstrap.py", Line 190, in stage 2
import pip
ImportError: No module named 'pip'

I don't see pip under ~/openeis-2.x/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ and I see the line 126 in bootstrap.py is to run get_pip()

So, I am still confused...

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow.   Open eis can run from the Windows installer as well.  However it looks like you are going from Linux, correct?

Comment: I did successfully install OpenEIS in Windows, and started to use/learn it. Eventually, I would love to have OpenEIS in Linux, so I can deploy it with VOLTTRON all together with one operating system. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Great.  I haven't had a chance to do the install on linux yet.  Sorry things have been really busy around here.

Comment: Please let me know if you had time to try, no rush.